# left inverse and right inverse of matrices

Tags: matrices, inverse, transpose

If $A \in R^{m×n}$ has a left inverse, $A^{T}$ has a right inverse. How I can prove this property? I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Sorry, for the close. I thought you wanted to know how to show that a left inverse is the right inverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $L$ be the left inverse of $A$. Then

$$LA=I.$$

Now transpose the equation $A^TL^T=I^T$.

Answer (score 1):

If $B$ is a left inverse of $A$, then $B^T$ is a right inverse of $A^T$, because$$A^TB^T=(BA)^T=\operatorname{Id}^T=\operatorname{Id}.$$